# Pandas Group by and find count of common strings

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My Dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'company':['Chipotle','Branchburg Chipotle','Chipotle NJ','Chipotle 8853','The Home Depot','Home Depot','28211 Home Depot','Wendys','BJs','Buffalo wings'],
'address':['123 Main Street Branchburg NJ 08853'
,'123 Main Street Branchburg NJ 08853'
,'123 Main Street Branchburg NJ 08853'
,'123 Main Street Branchburg NJ 08853'
,'1220 N Wendover Rd Charlotte NC 28211'
,'1220 N Wendover Rd Charlotte NC 28211'
,'1220 N Wendover Rd Charlotte NC 28211'
,'2805 Whitson St Selma CA 93662'
,'2805 Whitson St Selma CA 93662'
,'2805 Whitson St Selma CA 93662']})

    company                    address
0   Chipotle            123 Main Street Branchburg NJ 08853
1   Branchburg Chipotle 123 Main Street Branchburg NJ 08853
2   Chipotle NJ         123 Main Street Branchburg NJ 08853
3   Chipotle 8853       123 Main Street Branchburg NJ 08853
4   The Home Depot      1220 N Wendover Rd Charlotte NC 28211
5   Home Depot          1220 N Wendover Rd Charlotte NC 28211
6   28211 Home Depot    1220 N Wendover Rd Charlotte NC 28211
7   Wendy's             2805 Whitson St Selma CA 93662
8   BJ's                2805 Whitson St Selma CA 93662
9   Buffalo wings       2805 Whitson St Selma CA 93662
```

I have to groupby Address and find the common word in the company column and write that to a new column 'count'. so for first address the common word is chipotle so count is 1 and for second address common word is home depot so count 2 and for third address no common words so count 0

Expected Ouput

```
     company        address                               count
0   Chipotle        123 Main Street Branchburg NJ 08853     1
1   The Home Depot  1220 N Wendover Rd Charlotte NC 28211   2
2   Wendy's         2805 Whitson St Selma CA 93662          0
```

I can think of iterating through the dataframe and using set intersection but that's too slow process. Is there any pandas way to achieve this?

Comment: Given that `company` is a string, "The Home Depot" occurs actually once not twice.

Comment: Your logic still seems odd. For all three addresses, the largest value count for any unique company name is always 1, yet you seem to arrive at different counts for every address. It seems like you may really want the counts based on substring matches, but then the values you report for 'company` don't make sense And how do you want to define substrings? Should it be `'Home Depot'` or just `'Home'` or just `'Depot'`? Or am I just missing something completely?

Comment: my logic is same as set intersection, home depot is two words and not single, i realised now, updated my Question.

Comment: How come `The Home Depot` count is 2 while `Chipotle` count is 1?

Comment: @iDrwish Read Documentation for sets that would help to build up basics here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce
import operator
def log(x):
    inters = reduce(operator.and_, [set(r) for r in x.str.split()])
    if inters: return (' '.join(inters), len(inters))
    return (x.iloc[0], 0)
df.groupby('address').agg(log).company.apply(pd.Series).rename({0: 'company', 1: 'count'}, axis=1)

                                        company     count
address     
1220 N Wendover Rd Charlotte NC 28211   Home Depot  2
123 Main Street Branchburg NJ 08853     Chipotle    1
2805 Whitson St Selma CA 93662          Wendys      0
```

If pandas 0.20

```
.rename(columns={0: 'company', 1: 'count'})
```

Comment: what version of pandas you are using? It's throwing rename() got an unexpected keyword argument "axis" for 0.20.3

Comment: I'm using 0.23. No worries, I'll post a solution for that. @min2bro see edited answer

Comment: this solution doesn't work if there are 5 rows and only 3 rows have the common words, ex: Chipotle, Chipotle 7654,Branch Chipotle, Old Navy, Sears. in this case it gives value as 0